# Adding additional newline between each line

Tags: linux, sed, grep, tr, less-unix

I am analyzing log files from my server(particular few lines from there). But those lines are having around 1000 to 2000 characters in length.

Here is an example how the lines are coming out with `grep` and `less` with following command.

```
tail -n 1000 log.log | grep 'SOME_TEXT' | less
```

Output:

```
random text SOME_TEXT another 1000 chars
random SOME_TEXT 2000 chars
text text SOME_TEXT 2000 chars
```

But its hard for me to separate them as those are screen full of texts(also not pleasant for eyes either). I want to have my output like blow:

```
random text SOME_TEXT another 1000 chars

random SOME_TEXT 2000 chars

text text SOME_TEXT 2000 chars
```

And I have modified my above command with `sed`:

```
tail -n 1000 log.log | grep 'SOME_TEXT' | sed 's/\n/\n\n/' | less
```

It didn't work, so I tried with `tr` next:

```
tail -n 1000 log.log | grep 'SOME_TEXT' | tr '\n' '\n\n' | less
```

It didn't work with me either. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed G file
```

Comment: grouping with SOME_TEXT grep, in his sample seems better but you have the shortest, efficient one for the exact request 1Up

Answer (score 2):

This will search for `pattern` and print only `pattern` with an extra blank line after it.

```
awk '/SOME_TEXT/ {print $0 RS}' file
```

Example:

```
cat file
test
more
SOME_TEXT my data
more
even more
SOME_TEXT need more
more data
yes
```

```
awk '/SOME_TEXT/ {print $0 RS}' file
SOME_TEXT my data

SOME_TEXT need more
```

---

To print all text, with a blank line after `pattern`

```
awk '8; /SOME_TEXT/ {print ""}' file
test
more
SOME_TEXT my data

more
even more
SOME_TEXT need more

more data
yes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed '/SOME_TEXT/s/.*/&\n/g' logfile.log
```

Or

```
sed '/SOME_TEXT/G' logfile.log
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -n 1000 log.log | sed -n '/SOME_TEXT/ {G;p;}'
```

use the hold buffer

u can also number the line as separation

```
tail -n 1000 log.log | sed -n '/SOME_TEXT/ {=;p;}'
```